# Split a label in Arc GIS

Tags: split, label, arcgis, arcmap

I have a label in ArcGIS which produces a result of

```
BIN187
BIN2930
BIN190
BIN1290
BIN1920
```

etc

What I would like to do is have the label ignore the "BIN" part of the label and only display the numbers eg

```
187
2930
190
1290
1920
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to address this.

1. You could add a new field and calculate the new field to be: RIGHT(field name(len-4))
2. You could use the expression above in the layer properties box.